# An irreducible and not separable polynomial

Tags: field-theory

How can I show that $Y^3 - X$ is irreducible and not separable polynomial in $({\mathbb{Z}}_3(X))[Y]$? I am defining ${\mathbb{Z}}_3$ as $\mathbb{Z} / (3)$. It looks a strange field for me and my attemps do not reach any result. If $F$ is a field, I define $F(X)$ as
$$
F(X) = \left\{\frac{p(X)}{q(X)} : p(X) , q(X) \in F[X] \quad \mbox{ and } \quad q(X) \not \equiv 0\right\}\mbox{,}
$$
being $F[X]$ the set of polynomials with coefficients in $F$. I have seen the next argument to show the not separability: if $\alpha$ is a root of $Y^3 - X$, then
$$
Y^3 - X = Y^3 - {\alpha}^3 = {(Y - \alpha)}^3\mbox{.}
$$
The first step is clear but I don't understand the second step. What are we applying here?

Comment: There is a nice answer to this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147162/101420

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Irreducible: cubic is irreducible iff it has no roots. Use the fact that $\Bbb Z_3[X]$ is a graded ring to show that there is no roots: If $(f/g)^3 - X = 0$ where $f, g \in \Bbb Z_3[X]$, then $f^3 = Xg^3$. Now take the valuation (degree) of both sides.

Inseparable: $D(Y^3-X) = 3Y^2 = 0$

---

$Y^3 - X = (Y-\alpha)^3$ so you have multiple roots. That's like the definition of inseparability.

Comment: Yes I know the definition of inseparability but why $Y^3 - {\alpha}^3 = (Y - \alpha)^3$?

Comment: Just expand it out, bearing in mind that $3 = 0$.

Comment: Okay I know that it is not separable. But how can I use that ${\mathbb{Z}}_3(X)$ is a graded ring to show that there are no roots?

Comment: It is a field too

Comment: Is $\Bbb Z_3(X)$ really a graded ring? How do you decompose $\frac{1}{X+1}$ into a sum of homogenous elements?

Comment: Corrected: $\Bbb Z_3[X]$ is a graded ring.

Comment: If $(f/g)^3 - X = 0$, then $f^3 = Xg^3$. Take the valuation of both sides (i.e. the degree).

Comment: @Arthur $\Bbb Z_3(X)$ is the fraction field of $\Bbb Z_3[X]$

Comment: If I take the degree in the equation $f^3(X) = X g^3(X)$, I obtain that $\deg f^3(X) = 1 + \deg g^3(X)$, which is the contradiction?

Comment: The contradiction is when you move the cube outside the degree

Comment: Do you mean when $3 \deg f(X) = 1 + 3 \deg g(X)$?

Comment: Because this equation is equivalent to $0 = 1$, right?

Comment: Yes.$ {} {} {} $

Comment: Thank you very much by your help

Comment: Why cubic is irreducible iff it has no roots?